# Laravel sanctum api not working in cpanel

Tags: laravel

Hello please after setting up Laravel sanctum it works locally but on cpanel it doesn't..

I have the register and login api those works perfectly cause they ain't surrounded by the sanctum middleware .. but the remaining url within the middleware doesn't work.. any reason why?

Comment: maybe provide some code? in this case, problem should be related to authenticated user after login.

Answer (score 1):

This issue may be due to the htaccess file

**Just Add**

`RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$ RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]`

**After**

```
RewriteEngine On
```